# How to display upcoming birthdays?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date

I know I'm not the first one who is asking how to display upcoming birthdays. But unfortunately all the other answers didn't help me finding out how to do it.

I have a database with the following structure:

```
Id    -    Birthday
1          9/14/1996
2          8/27/1990
--         --
```

As you see, in the Birthday field the date of birth is stored. And I would like to show the five upcoming birthdays (including the birthdays today).

But how can I do that? I tried this, but it didn't work:

```
    $query="SELECT Id 
    FROM participants
    WHERE DATE_ADD(STR_TO_DATE(birthday, %n/%j/%Y), INTERVAL YEAR(CURDATE())-YEAR(STR_TO_DATE(birthday, %n/%j/%Y)) YEAR)";
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key to this question is to order things, not to use `where`.  This prevents a problem at the end of the year.

So, the logic is to put everything who MM-DD birthday is on or after the current date first, followed by the rest of the birthday in date order:

```
select p.*
from participants
order by (case when date_format(STR_TO_DATE(birthday, %n/%j/%Y), '%m-%d') >= date_format(now(), '%m-%d')
               then 0 else 1
          end),
         date_format(STR_TO_DATE(birthday, %n/%j/%Y), '%m-%d')
limit 5;
```

EDIT:

If you need to convert the birthdate:

```
select p.*
from participants
order by (case when date_format(birthdate, '%m-%d') >= date_format(now(), '%m-%d')
               then 0 else 1
          end),
         date_format(birthdate, '%m-%d')
limit 5;
```

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately everything is sorted by ID (order of database content), not on birthday. Perhaps it is because the Birtday field is a tinytext field? Should I convert it to Date first?

Comment: @Jordy . . . The question shows the birthday as a date field.  So, yes, you should convert it to a date.

Comment: If your field is a timestamp, you still need to convert it via FROM_UNIXTIME(birthday)

Answer (score 1):

```
select top 5 * 
from myTable 
where 
      month(dob) >= month(now()) 
  and day(dob) >= day(now()) 
order by dob asc
```

Comment: The birthday field contains the date of birth, not the upcoming date of the next birthday.

Comment: [FUNCTION myname.getdate does not exist]

Comment: you are using my-sql or sql server?

Comment: for my-sql, user NOW() insted of getdate().

Comment: Not reliable. E.g: If there are only 2 birthdays in December, when December comes, you would only see 2 upcoming birthdays, since January is indeed less than December. The query would start working properly again on the 1st of January.